# Using Poisson to calculate the probability of total number of goals scored in a certain number of matches

Tags: poisson-distribution

I know I can use the Poisson distribution to calculate the probability of x goals being scored in a match, based on the average number of goals scored per game in that particular league.

However, how do I calculate the probability of, for example, at least 31 goals scored in total across 8 matches in the same league, assuming I know the average number of goals scored per match in that league is 3.3?

Thanks.

Comment: The expected number of goals is $\lambda=8\cdot3.3=26.4$,  The formula for Poisson distribution is $e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$.

Comment: Thanks. What is k?

Comment: It might be useful to read a bit about the [Poisson Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Probability_of_events_for_a_Poisson_distribution).

Comment: Yes sorry, pretty obvious really. Thanks for your help.

Comment: To take this on another step, how do I calculate the probability of at least 50 goals being scored across two leagues with different averages of goals per game?

For example, league 1 averages 3.3 goals per game, 8 games to be played, λ = 26.4.
League 2 averages 2.2 goals per game, 10 games to be played, λ = 22.

I assume it's not as simple as using the Poisson of the sum of the expected number of goals from the two leagues, i.e. 48.4?

Comment: I think that two different leagues are independent so I guess given the fact that you already know the prob of X goals for league 1 and Y goals for league 2, you can find all the combinations of X+Y >=50 and then sumproduct the corresponding probs.